# Restoring a folder from sbackup archives

Tags: ubuntu, backup, restore

I am using sbackup(Simple Backup) tool on Ubuntu 10.04. It is set to take full backups per month and incremental backups everyday.

When I needed to rollback a software project of mine, I saw that its restore counterpart is quiet stupid, and can recover only the files that are only contained in a very specific archive. How can I recover a whole folder, without manually applying every incremental step after the full backup? I can try to write a script that uses the CLI but I want to learn if there is a better solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this situation by recovering the folder step-by-step, first the latest full backup, then all the incremental ones in order. The script was ad-hoc copy+paste. Looked like this

```
...
srestore.py /path/to/backup/2010-09-19* /path/to/data /path/to/restore
srestore.py /path/to/backup/2010-09-20* /path/to/data /path/to/restore
srestore.py /path/to/backup/2010-09-21* /path/to/data /path/to/restore
...
```